# Pcaprub Methods

Tags: ruby, networking, pcap

I checked out pcaprub's documentation [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pcaprub/0.11.2/frames.)

I didn't see any methods to learn about at the documentation site. It is a very thin documentation! Where can I go to find Pcaprub's methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Manual: http://rubypcap.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rubypcap/doc/index.html
Example: http://rubypcap.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rubypcap/examples/
More: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/rubypcap/
Github ReadME: https://github.com/shadowbq/pcaprub